# Find documents with array that doesn't contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following model:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    groups: [
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}
    ],
});
```

I am looking for a query that retrieves all the Persons that are not part of a certain Group (i.e the persons' group array doesn't contain the id of the specified group).

I was thinking about something like this, but I'm not sure it is correct:

`Person.find({groups: {$nin: [group._id]})`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you are basically attempting, but perhaps the only clarification here is the common misconception that you need operators like [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) or [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) when querying an array.

Also you really need to do here is a basic inequality match with [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/):

```js
Person.find({ "groups": { "$ne": group._id } })
```

The "array" operators are not for "array targets" but for providing a "list" of conditions to test in a convenient form.

```js
Person.find({ "groups": { "$nin": [oneId, twoId,threeId] } })
```

So just use normal operators for single conditions, and save `$in` and `$nin` for where you want to test more than one condition against either a single value or a list. So it's just the other way around.

If you do need to pass a "list" of arguments where "none" of those in the provided list match the contents of the array then you reverse the logic with the [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator and the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```js
Person.find({ "groups": { "$not": { "$all": [oneId,twoId,threeId] } } })
```

So that means that "none of the list" provided are present in the array.

Comment: Just to be sure, isn't the query you proposed going to return all Persons where at least one element from the groups array is different from group._id? (I need all of the elements from the groups array to be different)

Comment: @Marius You are only passing in a single element, albeit wrapping that in an array for the sake of the operator `[group._id]`. If you intend to pass a "list" and make sure that none of those items in the list are present, then there is another way to represent that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a better way to do this in Mongoose v5.11:

```
Person.find({ occupation: /host/ }).where('groups').nin(['group1', 'group2']);
```

The code becomes clearer and has more readability.