# Mongodb array query: find records that contain an outsider in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database for my image tags with a web UI for labeling the tags.  The tags are stored in documents with the following structure:

```
{
 imgID: 'UID of corresponding image',
 tagID: 'UID of tag',
 coordinates:{x1,y1,x2,y2},
 tags:[
    {tag:'a', user:'username'},
    {tag:'a', user:'username'},
    {tag:'typo', user:'username'}
]
}
```

I am looking for documents that contain incorrect tags, `typo`, in my example.
I tried

```
find({$and:[{'tags.tag':{$ne:'a'}},{'tags.tag':'a'}]}),
```

and

```
aggregate([{
    $match:{'tags.tag':'a'}
},{
    $match:{'tags.tag':{$ne:'a'}}
}])`
```

This is not a duplicate of [Find documents with array that doesn't contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481326/find-documents-with-array-that-doesnt-contains-a-specific-value) as I am looking for a document containing an array that DOES contain the value in question while at the same time contains ANY OTHER value. The solutions presented in that question do not work in my situation as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) to specify the `$ne` part of your query:

```
db.col.find({ $and:[ {'tags.tag': 'a' }, { tags: { $elemMatch: { 'tag': { $ne: 'a' } } } } ] })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use $elematch for matching elements of an array

db.col.find({ $and:[ {'tags.tag': 'a' }, { tags: { $elemMatch: { 'tag': { $ne: 'a' } } } } ] })